# WPF control for UI prototyping thumbnail view

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, controls

I am coding a state based UI prototyping application in which I want something like a [Slide view](http://0.tqn.com/d/presentationsoft/1/0/5/T/-/-/slides-outline-pane-powerpoint.png) (as in powerpoint 2010) and drawable canvas where a user can drag and drop a button and textbox from the toolbox, much like in WPF designer. Which controls can I use for

1. slide view
2. canvas
3. toolbox

Example code for UI is :

```
<screen>
      <components>
        <textfield x="50" y="120" width="924" textsize="50" background="1" border="1">
          <text say="1">
            <part type="text">Still I am taking the measurement. Please wait. If you want to terminate this process, please press SKIP.</part>
          </text>
        </textfield>

            <button label="SKIP" width="200" height="200" x="412" y="500" textsize="40" icon="none" adjtext="30">
                <event name="clicked">
                    <action preconditions="no" name="transition">
                        <parameter>
                            <type>state</type>
                            <name>n</name>
                            <value>4192</value>
                        </parameter>
                    </action>
                </event>
        </button>
      </components>
    </screen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want readymade controls? Then there are too many.... Infragistics NetAdvantage has some cool stuff that you can use, WPF toolkit offers a few....

But again WPF does not stop you here... templates, styles, themes, Drawing can do wonders...  `ListBox` of UI snapshot `Drawing` for slide view, `Toolbar` with image buttons for toolbox and a `Canvas` for canvas can serve you all right.

Comment: I've added an example. is there an example where I can create several state(each state having UI elements as in the example) and I can drag and drop button from the toolbox to the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the canvas but for your toolbox and slide view you can use something like a ListView with an itemtemplate to make the items display however you like.

You may wish to look into creating a UserControl to get any specific functionality you need. WPF is extremely powerful in this regard as you can extend the existing controls to do what you need. The slide view is obviously going to be more complex than the toolbox as I guess you want a realtime view of what is on each 'slide'

Comment: I've added the description of my UI language code. Its different from xaml. The app i need is a very minimal version of WPF designer. I don't want to use MS DSL tools for this because, I don't need the whole lot of other features DSL brings in. My functionality requirement is lesser that what the Visual Studio Integrated shell offers for example and I don't want anything as VSIX in the integrated mode. I want to have a separate application altogether which can be simpler and more customizable